# Ruby Cucumber: Selenium Webdirver - IE 11 link flashes, cannot click on

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, page-object-gem

I am experiencing IE browser links flashing issue when I run test automation written in Ruby Cucumber using Selenium WebDriver.

```
   Scenario: Navigating to Reporting home page.
      Given I see menu Reporting available.
      When I navigate to "Annual Reporting".
      Then I see the correct header on Annual Reporting page.
```

home_page.rb (Approach 1: using page_object)

```
     link(:annual_reporting_link, :id => 'annualReportingLinkId')

     def go_to_reporting
       mouse_over_home
       wait_until(5) do
           annual_reporting_link
       end
    end
```

Result: Could not click on the link because of the link flashing.

Then I tried the following (Approach 2: Using send_keys)

```
    @browser.find_element(:id, 'annualReportingLinkId').send_keys :return

    and 

    @browser.find_element(:id, 'annualReportingLinkId').send_keys(KEYS.ENTER)
```

but it did not work either.  I am getting this error when run the test:

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Cannot click on element
```

The HTML:

```
     <div id="homeMenu">
        <ul>
         <li class="has-sub"><a class="homeButton" href="/report-web"></a>
          <ul id="homeLinks">
             <li id="report1LiId"><a href="/report-web/openItems?subApp=report1&amp;rptid=15" id="report1LinkId" class="disabledLinks"><span id="report1LinkName" class="disabledLinksText">Report 1</span></a></li>
             <li id="report2Id"><a href="/report-web/realms?subApp=report2&amp;rptid=16" id="report2LinkId" class="disabledLinks"><span id="report2LinkName" class="disabledLinksText">Report 2</span></a></li>
             <li id="annualLiId"><a href="/report-web?subApp=annual" id="annualReportingLinkId"><span id="annualReportingLinkName">Annual Reporting</span></a></li>
             <li id="administrationLiId"><a href="/report-web/administration?subApp=ADMIN" id="administrationLinkId" class="disabledLinks"><span id="administrationLinkName" class="disabledLinksText">Manage Users</span></a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Test automation is able to expend the home menu, which contains sub-menus - hyperlinks. But after mouse_over_home (the home menu), the sub-menu started flashing. I need to click on "annual_reporting_link" to go to this reporting page, but because of flashing, the test automation cannot click on it at all.

Anyone has a solution that worked for you? Please share your solution.

Environment:

```
   Ruby: 1.9.3
   Cucumber: 2.1.0
   Selenium Webdriver: 2.53.4 
   page-object: 1.2.0
   IE: 11
```

Comment: Please post the (minimal amount of) `selenium-webdriver` code required to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I just edited my question with some code. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the "link flashes"? Is this a navigation menu that you need to hover over to click sub-menu links? If so, how are you expanding the menu - ie what does `mouse_over_home` do?

Comment: Hi Justin, I just updated my question above with your questions. Yes, I need to hover over to click sub-menu links. Please let me know what your thoughts are. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Justin, it sounds like you might have experienced the same issue with IE browser using Selenium WebDriver. Do you know if there is any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you extract the HTML/CSS/JavaScript of the page needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Justin, I added the HTML of the page. Hope it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before using Selenium Webdriver and IE. I found that it was a bug between my version of IE and Selenium Webdriver.

When I experienced this problem, I put a break-point before the link was clicked and debugged the test, I then manually tried to click the link in IE and I was still unable to do so 9 times out of 10 because of this bug, the link was simply ''flashing'' and unresponsive.

I'd recommend upgrading your version of Selenium Webdriver to version 3.0.0, that should fix the problem.

If you don't want to make the jump to Selenium Webdriver 3.0.0, You need find out the exact version of IE 11 you're using. Try to upgrade or downgrade your version of IE 11, this should also fix the problem, but you may find you're stuck on a version of IE 11 until you upgrade to Selenium Webdriver 3.0.0.

Antoher solution is to set the persistent hovers to false within your IE profile, something like this:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::IE::Profile.new
profile['enablePersistentHover'] = false

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :IE, :profile => profile
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for your message. I upgraded my Ruby to 2.3 and upgraded Selenium Webdriver to 3.0.0 . My Gemfile.lock file shows `selenium-webdriver (3.0.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0) `  Are these the ones you have? But I am still getting the same link flashes error.  What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Hi fongfong, what version of IE 11 do you have? Thanks, Dan

Comment: Hi Dan, IE Version is 11.0.9600.18524CO. (I forgot to mention that I also upgraded page-object gem to 2.0.0 to use Selenium Webdriver gem 3.0.0). Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. upgrading my Selenium Webdriver and IE 11 worked for me. It appears that IE has a load of bugs with selenium webdriver. The last thing I can think of for you to try which I've read elsewhere, is to change your IE desired to disable Persistent Hovers. Something like this: 'caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internet_explorer
caps['enablePersistentHover'] = false

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => caps)'

Comment: Sorry the comment above is badly formatted and I'm unable to edit it, please see an updated version of the original answer above :)

Comment: Thanks, let me try that. And also, do you have the issue with closing the IE browser after each scenario runs? even use `browser.close`? (I am able to close firefox browser each time at a scenario finishes.) Thanks!

Comment: Hi fongfong, any joy with the last solution? I don't have problems closing the IE browser either. Do you have before and after hooks setup? for tagging scenarios, so for example @IE would run your test in the IE browser. I've had problems previously closing browsers, but when I setup a hooks file, they went away.

Comment: Hi Dan, this is what I tried: `elsif BROWSER_TYPE == 'ie'
      #Below is to solve IE protected mode issue
      caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internet_explorer(
          'ignoreProtectedModeSettings' => true,
          'enablePersistentHover' => false
      )
      browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:internet_explorer, :desired_capabilities => caps)`  But it is not working yet.  Regarding close IE browser, I had it in env.rb file. I have an environment variable `BROWSER_TYPE=ie` in `cucumber.yml` file, so I know what browser to use.